# how to create a class the right way

Tags: php, oop

I'm 5 years in Procedural php, Recently I decided to bite the bullet, and progress to OOP.
Now I'm triyng to create a basic ui class to manage a responsive admin template
This class is for the grid
I want to be able to do this

```
$grid = new Grid();
// a span is an area the father and the widget is the son, so spans have widgets inside.

// a span a width of 6
$span1 = $grid->span("6");

// a new widget inside span1
$span1->widget("icon", "title1", "content1");
// another new widget inside span1
$span1->widget("icon", "title2", "content2");

// a span a width of 4
$span2 = $grid->span("4");

// a new widget inside span2
$span2->widget("icon", "title1", "content1");
// another new widget inside span2
$span2->widget("icon", "title2", "content2");

// echo /return  results
$grid->render();
```

this is what I have so far, but I'm not sure how to procced.

```
class Grid{
    private $content;
    private $innerContent;
    private $spanResult;
    private $widgetResult;

    function span($size){
        $this->size = $size;
        $output = '<div class="span' . $size . '">';
            $output .= $this->innerContent;
        $output .= '</div>';

        $this->spanResult .= $output;
    }

    function widget($icon, $title, $content){
        $output = '<div class="widget widget-nopad">';
            $output .= '<div class="widget-header"> <i class="icon-' . $icon . '"></i>';
                $output .= '<h3>' . $title . '</h3>';
            $output .= '</div>';
            $output .= '<div class="widget-content">';
                $output .= $content;
            $output .= '</div>';
        $output .= '</div>';

        $this->widgetResult = $output;
    }

    function render(){

    }
}
```

thank you.

Comment: this should be on code review

Comment: I posted there, just now, not many people there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like, for starters, your span() method is not returning an object. You'll need to create a span object within the span() method and return it. The span object should have the widget() method within it and the widget() method should only assign data to the span object. All span objects, as they are created, should be stored for reference within the grid object that you've created. Then, the $grid->render() method should iterate through the $span objects and output them appropriately.

**EDIT:** Here is a basic usage example of what I'm thinking. I avoided using grid and instead wanted you to read through this example and see what it does.

```
<?php
// Table class to manage the table object
class Table 
{
    // Init the row collection
    private $rows;

    // Function to create a row and save it in the table object.
    function row()
    {
        // Create a row object.
        $row = new Row;

        // Save this row object in this table object.
        $this->rows[] = $row;

        // Return the row object for method chaining
        return $row;
    }

    // Function to render the table.
    function render()
    {
        // For each row in this table object...
        foreach($this->rows as $row)
        {
            // Var dump for temporary output!
            var_dump($row->getData());
        }
    }
}

// Create a row class to manage the row object
class Row
{
    // Init the data array to store this row's content.
    private $data;

    // Function to add a string to the data array of this particular row object.
    function addData($string)
    {
        // Append string to this row's data
        $this->data[] = $string;
    }

    // Basic function to return data specific to this row's object
    function getData()
    {
        // Return this row's data!
        return $this->data;
    }
}

// Create the table object
$table = new Table;

// Create your first row by using the table object and it's row method. 
// This will create the row object but also save it's reference within the table object.
// Once we have the row object, use it's addData method to add a string.
$row = $table->row();
$row->addData('Row One Data');

// Same as row one but with different data.
$row2 = $table->row();
$row2->addData('Row Two Data');

// Render this table object!
$table->render();
?>
```

This will output:

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Row One Data" } array(1) { [0]=> string(12) "Row Two Data" }
```

As a side note, I *currently* disagree with A.B's answer. I believe that this should not be built based on static methods. I would continue what you are doing as you will then be able to make a custom grid with any data in the future (or have multiple different grids output on the same page). I am open to someone convincing me otherwise, though. My thought process here is that we're trying to do something similar to [Magento's Grid.](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Adminhtml/Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid.html)

Comment: I'm sure this makes sense to anybody in the oop comunity, But not to me.
Can you please show me an example?

Comment: Updated answer, let me know what you think and if you need any more assistance.

Comment: Updated again, this time with comments for a brief explanation.

Comment: So I need to create another class for span?

Comment: Yup that's right, because the Grid will contain multiple, varying Spans, it's best to make Span it's own Class. Then, I would add the  widget() method to the span class as the widget should be contained as part of the span, correct? Or do you want the span to be a widget? Either way, span is best as it's own object with it's own set of methods to maintain that particular span's widgets/content, and then the table can iterate through the spans it contains to get content.

Comment: I understand your answer, but it is too much for me the handle, I will accept your answer, becues it is correct :) , and then I will head on to linda.com to learn OOP in depth, Thank you.